# mongoimport 3.0.6 strict json dbref

Tags: mongodb, mongoimport

I have following structure in json file which I am trying to import:

```
[
    {
        "$ref": "ObjectName",
        "$id": {
            "$oid": "4f835168e4b041cb4cf48119"
        }
    },
    {
        "$ref": "ObjectName",
        "$id": {
            "$oid": "4f834cade4b041cb4cf48108"
        }
    }, 
 .... more element in the array ...
]
```

Whey I try to import with --upsert I have following error:

> error inserting documents: Found $id field without a $ref before it,
>   which is invalid.

And behavior is different: when I executed several times different number of objects are imported, even sometimes I didn't receive this error. 
Also this was working in with mongodb version 2.6.11
The whole command is:

> mongoimport -d db -c collection -u admin -p *** --host somehost --upsert  --file
>   xx.json --jsonArray